# How do I direct link a view to a taxonomy menu?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, routes

I have created a vocabulary with over a hundred terms on three levels (parent/child/child) and used Taxonomy Menu to create a custom menu.  Selecting a menu item brings up a  default menu page with the description and a list of teasers of content that has the vocabulary term in a field.  I would like it to use a view to manage the content display.  IS there a way to direct the menu items to a view? I cannot find a way to change the link generated by the taxonomy menu module.

Edit to clarify the question: 
Taxonomy menu generates a user defined menu block that will call up the taxonomy term selected. Unfortunately it locks the path (so it can regenerate the menu from the vocabulary if it changes).   I am looking for a way to generate the menu but change the path to display the view rather than the term page offered by taxonomy menu.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your question, I think that you can show your menu with the `Expose Filter` fature of Views:

first add the filter related with your taxonomy:

[image: Add filter criteria]

then select the type of your menu (for example: dropdown) to expose:

[image: Configure extra settings for filter]

and finally, you can expose these filter to visitors, to allow them to select terms to see just the content related:

[image: Expose this filter option]

I hope I have understood, and that information be useful. Here is an example of the view with results according a selection:

[image: View]

Comment: Thanks, it is a good answer for exposing the terms. Please see my edit to the question for more info.